# Android Background drawable does not show up on smartphone

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with drawable on TextView. 
It shows up on Preview in Eclipse.
But when i Debug on my Smartphone (Android 4.1.2) , it does not show up

The drawable is named : **textview**

**main.xml**

```xml
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    **<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textview">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>**
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top|right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/share_btn"
        android:onClick="share"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_prev"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:text="@string/btn_previous"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp4"
            android:text="@string/btn_next"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_random"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:text="@string/btn_random"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here the drawable textview**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
<padding android:left="2dp" 
         android:right="2dp" 
         android:top="2dp"
         android:bottom="2dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#cc000000" />
    <corners android:radius="8dip" />    
</shape>
```

**The grey Background does not show up while running on Smartphone**

[image: layout]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot about what you are asking.

Comment: added the Preview of the IDE

Comment: I tried your code and it's working for me, can you just try to uninstall app from device then clean your project and again install and check.

Comment: Problem is still there after uninstalling and cleaning the project. When i create a new project it works... I think its a problem with the package name or versioning problem